# how to test async function with set timeout using jest

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to test async function wrapped with timeout using jest. I tried using jest.useFakeTimers() which also didn't worked. Can some one please guide how to test function inside set timeout. I also gone through jest documentation but was not able to get the solution for this.

```
    function foo() {
      this.bar();
      setTimeout(async () => {
        await this.testMeIfYouCan();
      }, 500);
    }
```

test code:

```
      it('should call testMeIfYouCan',() => {
          
          const spyOne = jest.spyOn(component, 'testMeIfYouCan');
          component.foo();
          jest.advanceTimersByTime(500);
          expect(spyOne).toBeCalled();
        });
```

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: async await usage in your code is weird. it is totally useless in both of places. What exactly is working not as you expect in the code above?

Comment: is the spy not being called?

Comment: yes. If i remove the set timeout from function then it is called and test get pass. I need to test with set timeout. In that case it is failing

Comment: `useFakeTimers` is a correct way to resolve your problem. could you also paste a code where you tried it and it didn't work?